# HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.Application vs HttpContext.Current.Application

Tags: asp.net, httpapplication, httpapplicationstate

If I want to store some Objects to share across pages and session which one should I use?

`HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.Application` or `HttpContext.Current.Application`.

I was using `HttpContext.Current.Application` but just got confused between the two.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They both refer to the same thing, the `HttpApplicationState`

Comment: Well that's what I thought, but wanted to confirm after some answer in msdn forum directed to a page where MS says that `Application` is just for backward compatibility to classic ASP. Thanks for clearing it.

Answer (score 3):

`Application` and `ApplicationInstance.Application` are two versions of the same HttpApplicationState object.

From the [HttpApplicationState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplicationstate(v=vs.110).aspx) reference:

> A single instance of an HttpApplicationState class is created the
>   first time a client requests any URL resource from within a particular
>   ASP.NET application virtual directory. A separate single instance is
>   created for each ASP.NET application on a Web server. A reference to
>   each instance is then exposed via the intrinsic Application object.

To summarize:

- `Application` object is global to the web server.
- `ApplicationInstance.Application` object is local to the application the request refers to. (e.g. site or virtual directory application)

This is further explained in this [blog post](http://debugguru.blogspot.com/2013/01/application-vs-applicationinstance.html).